# String format byte array in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string-formatting, pyserial, string-interpolation, python-bytearray

I am quite new to python and I am currently playing around with [pyserial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/)
and what I am basically doing is sending simple commands via UART. A simple command that I have is:

```
b'page 0\xff\xff\xff'
```

which basically says to the hardware "Go on page with index of 0" (It is a [Nextion display](https://nextion.itead.cc/)). What I want to do is to somehow parameterize this byte array be able to dynamically pass the **0**. I've read different topics on the internet of first making it a string and later one use **bytearray** but I was wondering if it is not possible to apply it here somehow using string interpolation or something.

**NOTE**: The **\xff**'s at the end are hardware specific and must be there.

Comment: Have u tried  `python` string formatter `format` ? as in `v=0; b'page {}\xff\xff\xff'.format(v)` ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'format'

Answer (score 1):

Did you check out the string format docs in python?

```
pageNum = 0
b'page {}\xff\xff\xff'.format(pageNum)
```

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting

Comment: I am getting an error using this approach stating: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: @user2128702, that's an unusual error message. AFAIK, Python 2.7 doesn't _have_ a type named "bytes". Python 3, however, does. Are you entirely sure you're using Python 2.7?

Comment: The exact version checked using 'python -V' is 2.7.13

Comment: With Python 2, `r'page {}\xff\xff\xff'.format(pageNum)`

Comment: @dawg this one doesn't seem to be an option also. I keep on getting: TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still interested of how I achieved my goal, I came to the following solution:

```
def __formatted_page_command(self, pageId): 
    # This is the representation of 'page 0\xff\xff\xff'. What we do here is to dynamically assign the page id. 
    commandAsBytesArray = [0x70,0x61,0x67,0x65,0x20,0x30,0xff, 0xff, 0xff] 
    commandAsBytesArray[5] = ord(str(pageId)) 
    return bytes(commandAsBytesArray)
```

So, in this way, I can dynamically get:

```
b'page 0\xff\xff\xff'
b'page 1\xff\xff\xff'
b'page 2\xff\xff\xff'
```

just by calling

```
self.__formatted_page_command(myPageId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for something else but found this in results. I could not help myself but to add a solution that seems so standard to me.

In Python 2 there is a lower level formatting construct that is faster than `.format` that is built into the language in the form of the builtin str's **mod** operator, `%`. I've been told that it either shares code with or mimicks C's stdlib printf style.

```
# you're pretty screwed if you have > 255 pages
# or if you're trying to go to the last page dynamically with -1
assert 0 <= pageId <= 0xff, "page out of range"
return b'page %s\xff\xff\xff' % pageId
```

There are [other options](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) but I prefer old-school simplicity.